# PyInstaller tkinter GUI will not write to CSV file

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have created a GUI using tkinter (Python3.7) that does computations and outputs the results to a CSV. The code works fine until I package it up using PyInstaller. the GUI launches from the exe and every functionality works except for the write functionality. Could this be a permissions thing? Is there some sort of error log I can check or create for investigation?. I am new to making GUIs so I am not familiar with these things. Any input appreciated. thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try to write? Does it write to the correct file in the incorrect location? An incorrect file in the correct location? The correct file in the correct location, but it writes bad data? Does it throw an error, and if so, what's the error?

Comment: It does literaly nothing. I have a button that I press in the GUI which should create the file on the desktop. but I press it and nothing happens. since its an exe I dont know how to look at the error log.. if there even is one.